# Form Validation, if is not blank do validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, validation-list-items

Hello i have a list with 2 date columns, **[Date1] , [Date2]**,

How do i excecute the next validation on te list validation, only if that fields are not empty:

**=[Date2]>[Date1]]**

i want the users can let empty that fields and only validate if the dates are entered. Thanks, im on sharepoint online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
=OR(ISBLANK([Date2]),[Date2]>[Date1])
```

Basically, save only if 1) Date2 is empty or Date2 value is greater than Date1

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, its not working, it may be because is a date field?

Comment: I found the problem the formula was okay, in my case the separator that works is not coma (','), but semicolon (';'), then the formula doesnt throw sintax errors

Comment: Great.  Good to know it worked.