# calculating date differences in custom list

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a custom list to track audit NC closures. Due date, actual closure date, days overdue  I want a field to calculate the number of days overdue the closure is.  If I do a `DATEDIF` the formula will error where there is no date in the actual closure date column.  How do I get it to calculate the days if there is no date?  I.E I want it to look at (TODAY-due date) if there is no date in the actual closure date column...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ISBLANK` function with `IF` statement something like:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Today()-[Due Date]), "TRUE - DO THIS" "FALSE - OR THIS)
```

I answered something similar [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214734/form-validation-if-is-not-blank-do-validation/214739#214739)

More information about ISBLANK [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IS-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087)

Answer (score 0):

In calculated columns, the functions [Today] and [Me] won`t work. You should create a column with value [Today] and use that column in your formula.

I haven`t tried this but you refer this [article](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/09/today-sharepoint-calculated-default-values/). It explains how we can replace Today in calculated column.